# How can I get rid of Dark Mode from MinervaNeue on Desktop Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

I am a logged-in user on Wikipedia, and I began to use the MinervaNeue theme by changing my user preferences the last time I logged onto Wikipedia. This was for the purpose of using dark mode. However, I decided to use the default Vector theme on Desktop Wikipedia again. But my Vector theme is stuck in Dark Mode, which I didn't even know was possible. I have changed my Firefox and Macbook settings to Light Mode to no avail. How can I recover Light Mode for the Vector Theme on Wikipedia?

Comment: I closed this question because it's a troubleshooting like questions and this kind of questions are not a good fit this site as they might require a lot of back and forth. See [Troubleshooting guidance](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3799/88163).

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue myself. Ensure that you are not using the Dark Mode gadget from [User:Volker E. (WMF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Volker_E._(WMF)/dark-mode). You can toggle this gadget by navigating to the [gadget subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-gadgets)  of user preferences and ensuring that both the utility module "Core styling for dark mode gadget" and the "Dark mode toggle" are both unselected. Or, you can leave them both selected and toggle the dark mode from the upper right corner of any Wikipedia page. When I had only the utility module selected, the dark mode toggle in the corner did not have any effect on the appearance of the page.

This issue actually is not related to MinervaNeue at all; this toggle will work in either theme.